# Проверить что после введенной даты далее идут даты подряд из введенного списка

Tags: java

У меня есть метод который принимает список выходных и дату и проверяет идут ли после этой даты подряд выходные из переданного списка. Метод отрабатывает хорошо когда я ввожу первый день который является праздником и после него тоже идут праздники. Однако когда я ввожу день который не является праздником,но после него идут праздники метод не отрабатывает никак.

К примеру в листе со списком выходных лежат следующие даты :

```
('2023-01-01')
('2023-01-02')
('2023-01-03')
('2023-01-04')
('2023-01-05')
('2023-01-06')
('2023-01-07')
('2023-01-08')
```

При вводе 2023-01-01 метод отрабатывает верно. Однако если рассмотреть пример в котором в список праздников приходит:

```
   ('2023-02-22')
   ('2023-02-23')
   ('2023-02-24')
```

То при вводе 2023-02-21 метод не отрабатывает. В чем моя проблема? Как можно подкорректировать код?

**Мой метод:**

```
private void resultWeekend(LocalDate inputDate,, List<LocalDate> allHolidays) {
    

    int inputIndex = allHolidays.indexOf(inputDate);
 
    if (inputIndex == -1) {
        System.out.println("Введенной даты нет в списке");
    }

 
    for (int i = inputIndex + 1; i < allHolidays.size(); i++) {
        LocalDate currentDate = allHolidays.get(i);
         
        if (currentDate.equals(inputDate.plusDays(i - inputIndex))) {
            System.out.println("Следующая дата после " + inputDate + " - " + currentDate);
        } else { 
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1**

В allHolidays лежат не только даты из примеров выше,этот лист содержит около сотни дат в отсортированном по дате порядке. Я ожидаю что при вводе даты,которая не содержится в листе будет произведена проверка что после нее (дата + 1 день) могут содержаться даты которые в этом листе есть

Comment: А почему он не отрабатывает на втором примере? Я запустил - отрабатывает. Показывает все даты из переданного списка: 22, 23 и 24 февраля.

Comment: @Byb действительно, если в листе только данные как в примере все работает. Однако если в листе будет много дат помимо нужных то в строчке currentDate.equals(...) условие не пройдет. Я хотел описать свой вопрос попроще,но видимо только запутал,прошу прощения

Comment: @User Уточните по условию. Вам нужно проверить, после введенной даты есть ли какие либо выходные и вывести их?

Comment: Вопрос не слишком понятен, приведите больше примеров того, какие результаты у вас получаются и какие вы ожидаете получить.

Comment: @kio да,есть ли даты в листе которые идут подряд после введенной. Надо наверное добавить что в листе лежат не только даты из условия. Там около сотни дат в отсортированном виде. при вводе 2023-02-21 я ожидаю получить ('2023-02-22')
   ('2023-02-23')
   ('2023-02-24') тк они есть в листе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вам необходимо делать следующее:

1. В списке искать не только переданную дату, но и следующий день, так мы проверим условие, когда переданный день не является праздником, но следующий за ним - праздник(о чем вы и спрашивали)
2. Если вам необходимо выводить даты, расположенные подряд, проверяйте в цикле текущую и следующую

Пример:

```
private void resultWeekend(LocalDate inputDate, List<LocalDate> allHolidays) {
    LocalDate nextDay = inputDate.plusDays(1);
    int inputIndex = allHolidays.indexOf(inputDate);

    if (inputIndex == -1) {
        inputIndex = allHolidays.indexOf(nextDay);

        if (inputIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("Date not found in the list");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Holidays after " + inputDate);

    for (int i = inputIndex; i < allHolidays.size(); i++) {
        LocalDate currentDate = allHolidays.get(i);

        if (currentDate.equals(inputDate)) { // если переданная дата праздничная, пропускаем
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(currentDate);

        if (i + 1 == allHolidays.size()) {
            break; // найденная дата - последний праздник в списке
        }

        if (!currentDate.plusDays(1).equals(allHolidays.get(i + 1))) { // проверяем конец цепочки дат
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

В текущем примере не учитывается несколько граничных ситуаций, наподобие переданная дата - праздничная, и является последним элементом в списке.

Comment: Спасибо,это именно то что мне нужно!